# HowTo create template of a container (e.x. std::map)?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers

So, I had a simple working code, for example

```
template <typename T, typename VALUE>
VALUE mapAt(T key)
{
    std::map<T, VALUE>::const_iterator item_i(MyMap.find(key))
                                      , end_i(MyMap.end());
    if (item_i == end_i)
    {
        throw std::exception("No such key!");
    }

    return (*item_i).second;
}
```

**Question**: is it possible to create a new *template* function without using `std::map`, but using different containers (e.x. `std::map`, `std::multimap`, ...), something like this:

```
template <class Container, typename T, typename VALUE>
VALUE mapAt(Container& MyMap, T key)
{
    Container<T, VALUE>::const_iterator item_i(MyMap.find(key))
                                       , end_i(MyMap.end());
    /* ... */
}
```

**Problem**: when i'm tring to use it, like:

```
std::map<int, char> my_map;
char ch = mapAt<std::map<int, char>(), int, char>(my_map, 123); // C2664 error
```

compiler gaves me an error:

> main.cpp(119) : error C2664: 'mapAt' :
>   cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' to
>   'std::map<_Kty,*Ty> (*_cdecl &)' 1>
>   with 1>        [ 1>
>   _Kty=int, 1>            _Ty=char 1>        ] 1>        No user-defined-conversion
>   operator available that can perform
>   this conversion, or the operator
>   cannot be called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
template <class Container>
typename Container::mapped_type mapAt(Container& MyMap, typename const Container::key_type& key)
{
    typename Container::const_iterator iter = MyMap.find(key);
    return iter->second;
}

int main()
{
    std::map<int, char> my_map;
    char ch = mapAt(my_map, 123); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :-) Your solution works great. I also figure out, that if I replace line `Container<T, VALUE>::const_iterator` with this `typename Container::const_iterator`, my example starts working too!